# Problemas al conectar con BD Cpanel

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, cpanel

estoy subiendo mi primera pagina web para un cliente al internet, la conexion a la base de datos en local no tengo problemas pero en el hosting no se que pasa,estoy intentanco conectar la DB en Cpanel pero al parecer hay ciertos errores que no se cuales son,  cree la base de datos la cual es `mirandae_comentarios` y la contraseña `Keisy0518` mi archivo ....

```
<?php

 $host="mirandaenloscomentarios.com";
 $user="mirandae_miranda";
 $pass="Keisy0518";
 $db="mirandae_comentarios";

$con= new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);

if (!$con) {

    echo "error".$con->error();
}else{

    echo"You are connected";
}

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la pagina:[noticias de RD](http://mirandaenloscomentarios.com/)

antes de la estructura  **html** agrago el `include"class/conexion.php"` y siempre entra en el segundo else no importa que yo trate de que falle la conexion al tratar de escribir el nombre de la base de datos mal siempre me imprime **You are connected** no entiendo que pasa alguien que me pueda orientar que se nececita del todo para que la conexion sea exita en  cpanel

Comment: me sale lo mismo

Comment: Escribe mal la contraseña en vez de la base de datos... si lo que quieres es hacerla fallar. En cuanto al host, deberías poner `localhost` o bien `127.0.0.1`

Comment: muchas gracis por su ayuda , lo que pasaba era que aun no le habia dado a crear usuario disculpen por la ignorancia soy novato en esto de Cpanel